# Question about the usage of std::move() in member overloading

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, dynamic-binding

This question comes from ***C++ Primer(5th Edition)***, the last topic *Simulating Virtual Copy* in Chapter 15.

Define two classed related by inheritance:

```
class Quote{
public:
virtual Quote* clone() const & {return new Quote(*this);}
virtual Quote* clone() && {return new Quote(std::move(*this));}
//other members
};

class Bulk_quote: public Quote{
public:
Bulk_quote* clone() const& {return new Bulk_quote(*this);}
Bulk_quote* clone() && {return new Bulk_quote(std::move(*this));}
//other members
    };
```

and a class employing them:

```
class {
public:
  void add_item(const Quote& sale)   //copy the given object
    { items.insert(std::shared_ptr<Quote>(sale.clone()));}
  void add_item(Quote&& sale)  //move the given object
    {items.insert(std::shared_ptr<Quote>(std::move(sale).clone()));}
//other memebers
private:
  static bool compare(const std::shared_ptr<Quote>& lhs,const std::shared_ptr<Quote>& rhs)
{return lhs->isbn() < rhs->isbn();}
std::multiset<std::shared_ptr<Quote>,decltype(compare)*> items(compare);
};
```

I am stuck in two observations:

(1) why `std::move(*this)` in definition of member `virtual Quote* clone()&&` ? To my understanding, this version can only be run on a modifiable rvalue(say, temporal objects) under the reference qualifier `&&`. May `std::move(*this)` be replaced by `*this`?

(2)Similar to (1), why `std::move(sale)` in the second definition of member `add_item` which can only be run on a object of rvalue. For rvalue reference `Quote&& sale` can only be bound to a rvalue, is `std::move(sale)` necessary?

For calling the second version of `add_item`, the book says "although the type of sale is an rvalue reference type, sale(like any other variable) is an lvalue". However, the verison `void add_item(const Quote& sale)` will be called if `sale` is an lvalue. Who can help me out?

Comment: Whenever something has a name (including `this`), it is handled as an lvalue. You may use `this` several times in the function, you don't want the first one to erase the object... So when you are ready to give up on the object, you have to say so with `std::move`. `&&` on the argument is for callers to call the right version, but internally it is essentially the same as `&`. l/rvalue is not a property of the object but how you refer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem confusing objects with expressions. Value category (lvalue or rvalue) is a property of an expression, not of an object, so even if, for example, `*this` refers to a temporary object, it **as an expression** is still an lvalue. So is `sale`.

There are complicated rules to determine whether an expression is an lvalue or rvalue. The related rules for your example are:

- expression of the form `*expr` is always an lvalue;
- an unqualified name of a variable as an expression is always an lvalue.